# PhantomJS Child Process Module

Tags: phantomjs

I've been trying to find out how to use PhantomJS's child process module, but documentation is very scarce: http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/

Where can I find more documentation on how to use the child process module? The API only documents the `spawn` command. How do I use `execFile` and `kill`? Are these all the methods there are? What does `communicate with them via stdin / stdout / stderr` mean?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what exactly is that you're trying to do and don't know how. The linked documentation page seems to contain enough information to work with a child process, either spawned or exec'ed.

Comment: I updated it. Mainly I do not understand what ExecFile does (there's no documentation on it). Also I do not understand what they mean when they say communicate to the process via stdout/err/etc. Is it just printing to those streams and then the other process reads it?

Comment: Gary, that's still too broad a question. `How do I use execFile and kill?` - exactly like it's shown in the doc page. `Are these all the methods there are?` For managing a subprocess? Yes. What else would you like? Guess it depends on what you're doing. `What does communicate with them via stdin / stdout / stderr mean` - you can read from stdout and stderr; write to stdin. Please, tell us what you're trying to do, then I will be able to provide a meaningful answer.